# How to get debug log for standalone svnkit on Linux

Tags: java, linux, debugging, java.util.logging, svnkit

We're trying to debug the behaviour of svnkit during checkout on Linux (Debian) that is related to a JDK/JVM bug described here

- http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8172578
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075484

We followed the steps described here
https://wiki.svnkit.com/Troubleshooting
by renaming the file conf/logging.properties.disabled to logging.properties and by also replacing the /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/logging.properties (which symlinks to /etc/java-8-openjdk/logging.properties)
This produces a log file under Windows (in the bin folder of the svnkit standalone), but has no effect under Linux.

Calling

```
./jsvn checkout --username XYZ --password ABC http://SVN_SERVER/svn/project/trunk/
```

makes `ps aux` tell us

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/conf/logging.properties -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -classpath /tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/svnkit-1.8.15.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/sequence-library-1.0.3.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/sqljet-1.1.10.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/trilead-ssh2-1.0.0-build221.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.svnkit-trilead-ssh2-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.core-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.sshagent-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/jsch.agentproxy.pageant-0.0.7.jar:/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/lib/svnkit-cli-1.8.15.jar org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN checkout --username XYZ --password ABC http://SVN_SERVER/svn/project/trunk/
```

where

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/svnkit-1.8.15/conf/logging.properties
```

is the part that tells us the renamed logging.properties file is being used to configure the logging.

The content of the logging.properties is

```
svnkit.level=FINEST
svnkit-network.level=FINEST
svnkit-wc.level=FINEST
svnkit-cli.level=FINEST
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = svnkit.%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 0
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Any ideas what we are doing wrong?

Comment: You are using a relative path as the FileHandler pattern.  Unless you know the working directory you should try an absolute path.

Comment: @jmehrens: That's good advice, I forgot to mention: We also tested using an absolute path - same result: no log file :)